# Does this "transpose block bootstrap" make any sense?

Tags: inference, bootstrap, treatment-effect

Say we have the following data

[image]

Say we are concerned with a linear regression model that is $\boldsymbol{y} = \alpha +  \boldsymbol{d} \beta + \boldsymbol{u}$ and that we are interested in the sampling distribution of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. <sub><sup>($\boldsymbol{y}$ and $\boldsymbol{u}$ are of no interest presently.)</sup></sub>

One possibility is to resort to [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)). Given that we (may) have [autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) at work through time, the bootstrap units are the [blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Block_bootstrap) indexed along the (discrete) line of individuals, so that, e.g. one of the resampled versions of our data can be

[image]

You may already have an idea of what my question is going to be about. Our table also contains a (boolean) variable related to whether a given subject has undergone (or not) a treatment, namely $\boldsymbol{d}$.

I am aware of techniques that deal with that kind of data – i.e. with [Treatment Effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_treatment_effect) – and, most of the time, they drive us out of the [statistical-inference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233235/what-distinction-is-there-between-statistical-inference-and-causal-inference) sphere toward that of the [randomization inference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRkUhg9Wb-I), e.g. [MacKinnon and Webb (2017)](http://qed.econ.queensu.ca/faculty/mackinnon/working-papers/qed_wp_1387.pdf). ***Something I would like to know is whether the technique I am going to describe has a name, or to the extreme, just makes (no?) sense.***

Given that one drawback of "naively" block-bootstrapping is the possibility of having $\boldsymbol{d}$ 100% constant, (which may lead to [singularity issues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/131396/801833) and, before that, simply breaks the balanced structure of our data), would it make sense to consider all the possible treated-vs-untreated pairs as resample blocks ? In the current toy case, this would lead to "build" and consider $(4/2)^2$ blocks

[image]

Taking care of keeping the original number of observations identical, we could rebuild $\binom{4}{2}=6$ new data.

What bothers me is that, proceeding in this way is actually equivalent to *i)* naivily resampling our data and *ii)* putting aside unbalanced (with-respect-to-$\boldsymbol{d}$) outcomes which, presented in this way, looks like [selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias), hence my question.